# MySQL Column Migration from UTF-8 to ASCII: Foreign Key and Unique Key constraints

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, collation

I'm trying to run this query on a mysql table:

`ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY bar varchar(256) CHARACTER SET ascii collate ascii_general_ci;`

which returns this error:

> Cannot delete rows from table which is parent in a foreign key constraint 'fooren_key_constraint' of table 'foo'

I found all rows in `foo` where `bar` has no ascii and removed them with no problem. Still got the above error.

I then removed the foreign constraint and got this error:

> Duplicate entry '????????????.com' for key 'foonique_constraint'

'????????????.com' doesn't exist within foo, so the charset/collation must be doing a conversion.

**How can I get around these errors? How does the character set migration work? Why does it delete rows in some cases and in others convert to '???'?**

Comment: Please provide a sample `bar` value before the failed conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you had non-ascii characters in the string before doing the conversion.  Since non-English accented letters, etc, have no mapping from any character set into Ascii, the conversion has turns the bytes into `?`.

Please provide some more details -- why you want ascii; what the text looked like before; `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; etc.